# Why is this code not printing the reviews of all available businesses?

Tags: python, json, csv, google-api, python-requests

I am trying to collect all available google reviews of a business. Just for an example, there are more then 10 urologists in Georgia, listed in google reviews. But, when I run this code it gives me information of only 4-5 urologists in a csv file. But, I want the information of all the businesses with at least one rating/review that are in listed in google reviews . What changes should I make in this code here ?
Thanks,

```
import requests
import csv
import pprint

#sending get request.
main_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?"
parameters = {"query":"Urologists, Georgia",
            "key":" "} #enter api key here.
resp = requests.get(main_api, parameters).json()


#it selects the places with at least one rating, and puts their place id in place_id.
place_id = []
for i in range(len(resp['results'])-1):
    if 'rating' in resp['results'][i]:
        place_id.append(resp['results'][i]['place_id'])

#creating a csv file and with headings.
with open("Urologists_FunGeorgia_Google.csv", "w") as toWrite:
    writer=csv.writer(toWrite)
    writer.writerow(['Date Collected',  'Health Care Provider', 'HCP location', 'Website Review is From', 'Specialty', 'Reviewer Name',\
        'Date of Review', 'Reviewer Demographics(gender/race)', 'Star Rating', 'How Many Stars', 'Other Meta-Data', 'Review', 'URL'])
    #getting responses using place ids collected in place_id.
    for ids in place_id:
        details_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?"
        parameters = {"placeid": ids,
                    "key":" " } #api key here.
        detail_resp = requests.get(details_api, parameters)
        resp1 = detail_resp.json()
        reviewss = resp1['result']['reviews']
        doc_name=resp1['result']['name']
        doc_url = resp1['result']['url']
        city_state = resp1['result']['formatted_address']
        website = 'GOOGLE'
        specialty = 'Urologists'
        date_collected = 'June 15 2017'
        total_poss = '5'
        #gets multiple reviews of the physician(if any).
        for i in range(len(reviewss)-1):
            rating = resp1['result']['reviews'][i]['rating']
            revname = resp1['result']['reviews'][i]['author_name']
            rev = resp1['result']['reviews'][i]['text']
            date_review = resp1['result']['reviews'][i]['relative_time_description']
            rev_url = resp1['result']['reviews'][i]['author_url']

            writer.writerow([date_collected, doc_name, city_state, website, specialty, revname, date_review, rev_url, rating, total_poss, '', rev, doc_url])
```

Comment: Why do you subtract 1 from the length of the lists that you're looping over?

Comment: The pythonic way to loop over a list is with `for item in list:`, not `for i in range(len(list)):`

Comment: @Barmar, so that it wont go out of the range.

Comment: `range(n)` returns a list that goes from `0` to `n-1`. It already subtracts 1 for you, you don't need to do that yourself.

Comment: have you looked at the JSON being returned to see if it has more than 4-5 results?

Comment: If I do that, I don't think it works for the first for loop. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. And the place_id has got more than 10 results(place ids).

Comment: `for result in resp['results']: if 'rating' in result: place_id.append(result['place_id'])` should work.

Comment: Can you update the question with the api's json result ? Will be easy to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you subtract 1 from `len(reviewss)` in the inner loop, you're skipping the last review. If a urologist only has 1 review, you'll skip that urologist completely. So you're only putting the urologists who have more than 1 review into your CSV file.

Get rid of `-1` in both `for` loops. But I suggest you change to the more pythonic `for item in list:` syntax, and a list comprehension when setting `place_id`.

Since some reviews don't have a `review_url` property, you need to supply a default. You can do this with `review.get('author_url', '')`

```
import requests
import csv
import pprint

#sending get request.
main_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?"
parameters = {"query":"Urologists, Georgia",
            "key":" "} #enter api key here.
resp = requests.get(main_api, parameters).json()

#it selects the places with at least one rating, and puts their place id in place_id.
place_id = [result['place_id'] for result in resp['results'] if 'rating' in result]

#creating a csv file and with headings.
with open("Urologists_FunGeorgia_Google.csv", "w") as toWrite:
    writer=csv.writer(toWrite)
    writer.writerow(['Date Collected',  'Health Care Provider', 'HCP location', 'Website Review is From', 'Specialty', 'Reviewer Name',\
        'Date of Review', 'Reviewer Demographics(gender/race)', 'Star Rating', 'How Many Stars', 'Other Meta-Data', 'Review', 'URL'])
    #getting responses using place ids collected in place_id.
    for ids in place_id:
        details_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?"
        parameters = {"placeid": ids,
                    "key":" " } #api key here.
        detail_resp = requests.get(details_api, parameters)
        result = detail_resp.json()['result']
        reviewss = result['reviews']
        doc_name=result['name']
        doc_url = result['url']
        city_state = result['formatted_address']
        website = 'GOOGLE'
        specialty = 'Urologists'
        date_collected = 'June 15 2017'
        total_poss = '5'
        #gets multiple reviews of the physician(if any).
        for review in reviewss:
            rating = review['rating']
            revname = review['author_name']
            rev = review['text']
            date_review = review['relative_time_description']
            rev_url = review.get('author_url', '')

            writer.writerow([date_collected, doc_name, city_state, website, specialty, revname, date_review, rev_url, rating, total_poss, '', rev, doc_url])
```

Comment: I made changes as you said. Now, it only prints few results(fewer then before) and gives this error: `KeyError: 'author_url'`.

Comment: That means some of the reviews don't have an `author_url` field. You need to check for this and provide a default value.